# Can I tell that a request has come from a server transfer, and is not user-initiated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpcontext

In .NET, is there any way that I can tell from the `HttpContext` or `HttpApplication` that a particular request is the result of a `Server.Transfer()` rather than a client-initiated request?

Comment: you could look at the HTTP_REFERRER header, but i'm not sure if it's set during a Server.Transfer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test Request.IsLocal to see if the request was from the local computer. Obviously, you will need to test this from a different computer to verify it is working.

Comment: Combination of this + checking if it's not in DEBUG (ie running on the local dev machine) worked, ta

Answer (score 0):

May be you may check the `PreviousHandler` property of current request. If value of `PreviousHandler` is null then it is client-initiated request.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.PreviousHandler == null)
  //
else
  //
```

Comment: PreviousHandler is null on the transferred request unfortunately